# Laravel Email Verification 5.7 using REST API

Tags: php, laravel, api, email, email-verification

How to remake Laravel 5.7 Email Verification for Rest API?

Or is it worth doing everything from scratch?

Comment: Well I implemented a section of your code, and noticed that you're using POST routes instead of GET? The email sends the params as a GET, and would throw an unknown method exception in that event.

Comment: I do not remember why I did it. I redid my question in response and changed the routes. Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This case works for me. Full project code [here](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel5.7-vue-cli3-boilerplate).

### 1) Redesigned **VerificationController** controller

Removed redirects and made `response()->json(...)` responses.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Show the email verification notice.
     *
     */
    public function show()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        // ->route('id') gets route user id and getKey() gets current user id() 
        // do not forget that you must send Authorization header to get the user from the request
        if ($request->route('id') == $request->user()->getKey() &&
            $request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }

        return response()->json('Email verified!');
//        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Resend the email verification notification.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->json('User already have verified email!', 422);
//            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }

        $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return response()->json('The notification has been resubmitted');
//        return back()->with('resent', true);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
}
```

### 2) Added my Notification:

I made it so that the link in the email message led to my frontend and contained a temporarySignedRoute link for the request.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailBase;

class VerifyEmail extends VerifyEmailBase
{
//    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        $prefix = config('frontend.url') . config('frontend.email_verify_url');
        $temporarySignedURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
        );

        // I use urlencode to pass a link to my frontend.
        return $prefix . urlencode($temporarySignedURL);
    }
}
```

### 3) Added config `frontend.php`:

```
return [
    'url' => env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:8080'),
    // path to my frontend page with query param queryURL(temporarySignedRoute URL)
    'email_verify_url' => env('FRONTEND_EMAIL_VERIFY_URL', '/verify-email?queryURL='),
];
```

### 4) Added to User model:

```
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
```

and

```
/**
 * Send the email verification notification.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new VerifyEmail); // my notification
}
```

### 5) Added routes

The following routes are used in Laravel:

```
// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

They are added to the application if used `Auth::routes();`.

As far as I understand the `email/verify` route and its method in the controller are not needed for Rest API.

### 6) On my frontend page `/verify-email`(from `frontend.php` config) i make a request to the address contained in the parameter `queryURL`

The received URL looks like this:

```
"http://localhost:8000/api/email/verify/6?expires=1537122891&signature=0e439ae2d511f4a04723a09f23d439ca96e96be54f7af322544fb76e3b39dd32"
```

My request(with Authorization header):

```
await this.$get(queryURL) // typical get request
```

---

The code perfectly verify the email and I can catch the error if it has already been verified. Also I can successfully resend the message to the email.

Did I make a mistake somewhere? Also I will be grateful if you improve something.

Comment: Privet ;) I am new to api programming and i just wondering, is it really restful if you have auth()->user()?

Comment: @nrkz Yes! but you still need to use `tymon/jwt-auth` package (for example), it integrates with built-in authorization, so `auth()->user()` works.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with your code. Really nice. But how do you use middleware to check if the user is verified?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько auth()->user()->getKey() = null i need to send the jwt token with The received URL  right ?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько , how can you append authorization header while verifying email, because it will be the link in mail, i can only append query parameters in it, i don't know how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried Илья Зеленько answer but I must modify VerificationController construct method as follow

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['verify','resend']);
    $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
    $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
}
```

otherwise laravel need autentication to access verify and resend routes

Comment: Maybe then you should remove `$this->middleware('auth')->except(['verify','resend']);` altogether? Since there are only two methods: `verify`, `resend`.In theory, you can also replace `$this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');` with `$this->middleware('throttle:6,1');`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Doesn't this kind of modification impose a security risk?