# Sending a verification email when registring from the api

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get Lavarel to send a verification email when you register through the API. Is this possible?

I've added the MustVerifyEmail implement to the User class and added Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); to almost the top of my api.php file (Where my routes are). Also the SMTP server is configured correctly.

I think I might be doing something wrong. Hope to hear from you :)

P.S. I've started using Laravel for the first time today. So it might just be a really simple mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Email Verification 5.7 using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362927/laravel-email-verification-5-7-using-rest-api)

Comment: It is not. I already found that post and it's about a rework for the verification email. I just want the verification email send that is already present in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom `RegisterController` you should be able to call

`$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();`

this in turn calls the

`$this->notify(new Notifications\VerifyEmail);`

This is because your user implements `MustVerifyEmail` in the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User.

EDIT----

You can also use the event `new Registered` which should be registered in the `EventServiceProvider` this will call the `SendEmailVerificationNotification` which in turn will call `$event->user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();`

```
event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
```

Note: this works in laravel 5.7

Comment: I indeed got a verification mail now! So thank you! But the mail doesn't work. It redirects to the login paga and doesnt verify the account. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); should it not be in web.php because thats where you will have a session. If you do it in api.php you will not be logged in therefore you would not be able to submit anything.